# Chek if a folder exist in a internal folders in a directory using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

For example I have 4 folders in `E:\`

How can I check if this folders contains a folder named `Face` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] directoriesToSearch = { "C:\\tmp\\test2", "C:\\tmp\\test", "C:\\tmp\\test3" };

    var directoriesContainingFace = directories.Where(d => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(d, "Face").Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: how is the second line???? it dosn't work .... how can I use directory.where ????? @user1965927

Comment: Sorry I was not using VS, replace directories with directoriesToSearch and it should do it